# Creating SSAS partitions from an XML file

Tags: stored-procedures, ssas, xmla

I have a requirement to create new partitions in a cube using stored procedures.
I have seen solutions using C#/VB/ but nothing for SP's

I have generated the CREATE XMLA but have no idea how to hand that off to SSAS to create the partiton

Any help would be greatly appriciated

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to cobble something together with a linked server. but I would look at one of these more common options:

SSIS DDL Task - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139988.aspx

SQL Agent XMLA Job Step - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187056.aspx

ascmd.exe - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365187(v=sql.90).aspx